# Necessary and enough condition for minimum of function

Tags: optimization

Let $F(x)=〈Ax,x〉+〈2b,x〉+c, x\in\mathbb R^n$, A is real, symmetric, regular and positive definite matrix, $a,b\in\mathbb R^n$, $c\in\mathbb R$ are fixed.

1. What is necessary condition for local minimum of F?
2. Is enough condition satisfied too?

I know that necessary condition is that differential of F, if exists, is 0.

I have this written in my notebook:

$F(x+h)-F(x)= 〈A(x+h),x+h〉+〈2b,x+h〉+c-〈Ax,x〉-〈2b,x〉-c=    〈Ax,x〉+〈Ax,h〉+〈Ah,x〉+〈Ah,h〉+〈2b,x〉+〈2b,h〉-〈Ax,x〉-〈2b,x〉= 〈Ax,h〉+〈Ah,x〉+〈Ah,h〉+〈2b,h〉= 2〈Ax,h〉+〈2b,h〉= 2〈Ax+b,h〉$

since h is not 0, this $F(x+h)-F(x)=0$ iff $Ax+b=0$ $=>$ $Ax=-b$ $=>$ $x=\frac{-b}{A}$.

What is not really clear to me is why

1. 〈Ah,x〉=〈Ax,h〉
2. 〈Ah,h〉=0
3. What is enough condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the inner product is the usual dot product.

1. Since $A$ is positive definite, it is self-adjoint. Thus $\langle Ah,x\rangle=\langle h,Ax\rangle=\langle Ax,h\rangle$.
2. When $h$ is nonzero, $\langle Ah,h\rangle$ must be nonzero too, because $A$ is *positive* definite. However, $\langle Ah,h\rangle=O(h^2)$. So, in first order approximation, $\langle Ah,h\rangle$ can be ignored when $h$ is small. By the way, what you should solve is **not** $F(x+h)-F(x)=0$ but $F(x+h)-F(x)=o(h)$. That is, you are going to find $x$ such that the *first-order* term in $h$ of $F(x+h)-F(x)$ is zero. Also, the solution is $x=-A^{-1}b$, not $x=\frac{-b}{A}$. Division of a vector by a matrix is in general undefined.
3. Yes. In fact, by completing square,
   $$F(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle+2\langle b,x\rangle+c=\left\langle A(x+A^{-1}b),(x+A^{-1}b)\right\rangle-\langle A^{-1}b,b\rangle+c.$$
   The two trailing terms on RHS are constants. As $A$ is positive definite, the least possible value of $\left\langle A(x+A^{-1}b),(x+A^{-1}b)\right\rangle$ is zero, which occurs when $x+A^{-1}b=0$, i.e. when $x=-A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand part 3.
How should I check if enough condition is satisfied?

And I know that I can't divide by A, I just didn't know how to write $x=-A^{-1}b$ (I was writing wrong bracket)

Comment: @gorica This is already shown in my answer to part 3, isn't it? You see, by saying that $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a **necessary** condition for $x$ to be a minimizer, what we mean is that if a minimum exists, the minimizer **has to be** $-A^{-1}b$. And by saying that $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a **sufficient** condition for $x$ to be a minimizer, we mean that the minimum of $F$ does occur at $x=-A^{-1}b$. Now what part 3 shows is exactly this: $\left\langle A(x+A^{-1}b),(x+A^{-1}b)\right\rangle$ is always nonnegative, regardless of $x$, and it is zero at $x=-A^{-1}b$. So $x=-A^{-1}b$ is indeed a minimum point.

Comment: which I still don't understand, sorry.
What am I asking is: "Is there any theorem that says something about sufficient condition for local extremes? Anything that includes second derivative? (because I have written just that since $F''=2A$ and A is positive definite, $x=-A^{-1}b$ is minimizer.

Comment: @gorica In this case, you may argue like this: Since the Hessian matrix of $F$ is $2A$, which is positive definite, the critical point $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a **local** minimum. However, as the Hessian matrix $2A$ is positive definite at **every** $x$, $F$ is a convex function. Every local minimum of a convex function is a global minimum. Hence $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a **global** minimum point.

Comment: ok, I know what is Hessian matrix, but I don't know how to find it for this function.
In general, if Hessian matrix is positive definite, than every local minimum is global minimum?

Comment: @gorica No. There are three separate facts. (1) If the Hessian matrix *evaluated at a critical point* is positive definite, then that critical point is a local minimum. (2) If the Hessian matrix is positive definite *everywhere*, the function is convex. (3) Every local minimum of a convex function is a global minimum. Combining these three facts, your $x=-A^{-1}b$ is a global minimum.

Comment: Thank you. I hope I will understand this :)